# Docker Image and Cloud Foundry Droplet similar?

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry, docker-image

I'm kind of new to these concepts, I've been reading the documentation of both Docker and Cloud Foundry. I found that both droplet in cloud foundry and docker image are similar but wanted to make sure I'm correct.

From my understanding, when docker image is run, it becomes a running process called a container. Does similar process take place on a cloud foundry droplet too during deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [How Applications Are Staged](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-11/concepts/how-applications-are-staged.html) explains the staging process for Cloud Foundry using its native `garden/garden-runc` containers. It also explains the staging process using docker images.

Comment: that link is to a 1391 page doc